# WAMP is not displaying the icons in the directory listing

Tags: php, permissions, wamp

In the past I have worked with my PHP code through vmware, but I recently decided to switch to doing it locally through WAMP (on Windows 8.1).

1. I created an empty folder `tests` in the `www` folder.
2. Then on my browser, I typed `http://localhost/tests`

Everything is fine except that the icons icons are not displayed. Here is a picture demonstrating what I mean:

[image: example without icons]

Is there a way to get these icons to display correctly?

Comment: If you try to visit these icons directly, what url are they pointing at, and what is being shown instead of the image?

Comment: I do not know because those icons are native icons from wamp.

Answer (score 6):

This has to do with the Apache indexer config file. Its a bug with the Wamp installer. It does not modify the httpd-autoindex.conf configuration file to point to the Wamp directory you specified.

Look in httpd-autoindex.conf and change the paths to point to where the icons are located. On my WampServer, they are located in c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/icons.

Here's the relevant area of httpd-autoindex.conf you need to change:

```
#Comment out and change below to appropriate icon path
#Alias /icons/ "c:/Apache24/icons/"
Alias /icons/ "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/icons/"

#Comment out and change below to appropriate icon path
#Directory "c:/Apache24/icons">
<Directory "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/icons/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

By default, WampServer should already have enabled the fancy directory listing in httpd.conf. If they are commented out, enable them:

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so

Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
```

Don't forget to reboot Apache after making these changes.

Comment: you mean I shall check on my httpd.conf file?

Comment: It solve my problem. I appreciate your support. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot ...
New wamp server 3 by default disable the fancy directory listing , I resolved that issue by loading mod_autoindex and include autoindex from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are running Apache.
Make sure your config file has an alias to icons as such:

```
Alias /icons/ "/usr/local/apache/icons/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a directory icons/ in my root directory, and could not load anything from icons/. It shows the server icons in place of anything was there.

In `C:/xampp/apache/conf/extra directory`, there is httpd-autoindex.conf, this has an Alias.

```
Alias /icons/ "C:/xampp/apache/icons/"
```

...and this is the problem.

I had to change it to something else

```
Alias /iconsZ/ "C:/xampp/apache/icons/"
```

and I changed all the references from the same file (httpd-autoindex.conf) to reflect the new Alias iconsZ/