# How to enable directory listing in a virtual host of WAMP Server 3

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, wamp, virtualhost

I am using **wamp server 3** in my local machine. Whenever I make a virtual host I have to provide at least one `index.php` file to access my project directory, without it I am getting an `404` error.

But I also want to access my project directory without providing the `index` file. I like to see the directory lists when server doesn't find an index file. Like the below image:

[image]

I think the issue is in my `httpd-vhost.conf` file. Here is the virtual-host configuration of the directory that I want to enable directory listing:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName virtualhost.info
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/virtual_host_test
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/virtual_host_test/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found one solution.

By default New Wamp disable the Fancy directory listings.

Edit the C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf\httpd.conf

Need to load this module (remove the #)

```
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

Need to load this conf (remove the #)

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
```

Reference links: [WAMP is not displaying the icons in the directory listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131555/wamp-is-not-displaying-the-icons-in-the-directory-listing)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName virtualhost.info
  DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/virtual_host_test
  <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/virtual_host_test/">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiView
      AllowOverride All
      Require local
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note the `+` at the start of the `Indexes` option. You should also read up on this.

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Comment: Not working yet. And when I check for errors with wamp's `Check httpd.conf syntex` tool I get the following syntax error:  `Either all Options must start with + or -, or no Option may.`  By the way when I changes the option according to you Wamp don't starts either.

Comment: Did you add the + to all options?

Comment: Yes I have added `+` to all options but still getting `404` error. But wamp has started after adding `+ ` to all options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **enable** directory browsing simply you need to do this under the *VirtualHost*

```
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
#Options -Indexes
```

and for **disabling** this feature you just reverse :

```
#Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
 Options -Indexes
```